# Save records in Sql database like chain (every record know contains the previous record xml Hash )

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, queue

I want to know what is the best way to save records in Sql server table as chain
Every record contains the previous record xml Hash and the operation before save takes some time .
I case of low traffic every thing works fine but in case of high traffic may be 2 record take the same previous record Id and this is big problem .

I tried save data without order in temp table and then run background job
read each record and then add to the correct table one by one
but not working correctly
I want to know what is the best way to do such tasks ?

Comment: Add a sequential ID using a stored procedure.  Then you do not have to link.  The previous ID is one less than current ID.  Make ID a primary Key so lookup is quicker.  SQL Server does not have links like other databases.

Comment: it should contains hash of the previous record also

Comment: A primary key is a hash of every value in the field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need hash of xml value of the previous record it's commercial invoices

Comment: I think there is two different hashes.  One for the dictionary lookup by by ID and one for the xml data.  When an unique ID gets assigned in a multi-user database you need to use a stored procedure which locks the database so duplicate IDs do not get assigned.